# Free group generated by two generators is isomorphic to product of two infinite cyclic groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

Is the following statement true or not?

> The free group generated by two generators is isomorphic to the direct product of two infinite cyclic groups.

I know that if the generated group is abelian then the statement is True but I don't know if it's not abelian. I think it's wrong but can't come up with a counter example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a question like this you really need to say how things are defined. For example, I think of the free group on two generators as the group with presentation $\langle a, b\mid-\rangle$ (two generators, no relators), and I think of the free product $\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle\ast\langle \mathbf{y}\mid\mathbf{s}\rangle$ over disjoint alphabets $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ as the group with presentation $\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\mid\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{s}\rangle$. Continued...

Comment: So if $\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle=\langle a\mid-\rangle$ and $\langle \mathbf{y}\mid\mathbf{s}\rangle=\langle b\mid-\rangle$ as in your question then the result is trivial...but this is because of my definitions.

Comment: Our definition of free group on two generators is same. But the product is simply like the cartesian product of two groups.

Comment: Then this does not hold: free groups are different from free abelian groups. $F(a, b)\cong\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}\not\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ (One way to see this is to use the universal property of $F(a, b)$ - you know there exist non-abelian two-generated groups, for example $S_5$, so $F(a, b)$ is not abelian. However, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian. Contradiction.)

Comment: Just for clarification ! you basically are trying to say that I can map 'a' to one element and 'b' to a different element of S5 such that both element  (mapped) in S5 generate S5. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As $S_5$ is non-abelian, and as being abelian is preserved under homomorphic images, then $F(a, b)$ is non-abelian.

Comment: In fact your question is  equivalent to asking whether all groups are abelian!

Answer (score 2):

> It is not true that the free group on two generators $F_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

To see this, suppose otherwise. Then $F_2$ is abelian. By the universal property of free groups, every group which can be generated by two elements is a homomorphic image of $F_2$. In particular, the symmetric group $S_5$ is a homomorphic image of $F_2$. As "being abelian" is preserved under homomorphic images, we have that $S_5$ is abelian. This is a contradiction.

(The above argument still works if you replace $S_5$ with your favourite two-generated, non-abelian group. For example, $S_3$, or any non-abelian simple group.)

EDIT: As Derek Holt pointed out in the comments to the question, this question is equivalent to asking whether all countable groups are abelian! This is because every countable group embeds into a two-generated group (which is a classical result: Higman, G. , Neumann, B. H. and Neuman, H. (1949), *Embedding Theorems for Groups.* Journal of the London Mathematical Society, s1-24: 247-254. doi:10.1112/jlms/s1-24.4.247).